# ¿Cómo puedo decir la cantidad de veces que se repite una vocal en una oración?

Tags: c, while

tengo que hacer un programa que pueda pedir una cadena de caracteres (string) a el usuario, ademas debe de indicar cuantas veces aparecen las vocales a, e, i, o, u; en la cadena de caracteres que se indico previamente y también decir, cuantas vocales tiene la oración en total.Ya logré que hacer que saliera el numero de vocales que tiene la oración indicada por el usuario, pero aun no logro hacer que el programa muestre las veces que una una de las vocales de arriba aparece en la oración dada por el usuario.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
int b,c;
char a[50];
int cuentaVocales(char *);
int v_a(char *);
int e(char *);
int v_i(char *);
int o(char *);
int u(char *);

printf("Escribe algo menor a 50 letras\n");
gets(a);
printf("%s",a);

printf("el numero de vocales es %i\n",cuentaVocales(a));
printf("la letra [a] aparece %i veces\n"),v_a(a);
printf("la letra [e] aparece %i veces\n"),e(a);
printf("la letra [i] aparece %i veces\n"),v_i(a);
printf("la letra [o] aparece %i veces\n"),o(a);
printf("la letra [u] aparece %i veces\n"),u(a);


getch();
return 0;
}
int cuentaVocales(char *s){
int cont=0;
while(*s){
    switch(*s){
        case'a':
        case'e':
        case'i':
        case'o':
        case'u':
            cont++;
    }
    s++;
}
return cont;
}
int v_a(char *c){
int cont=0;
while(*c){
    switch(*c){
        case'a':
            cont++;
    }
    c++;
}
return cont;
}
int e(char *c){
int cont=0;
while(*c){
    switch(*c){
        case'e':
            cont++;
    }
    c++;
}
return cont;
}
int v_i(char *c){
int cont=0;
while(*c){
    switch(*c){
        case'i':
            cont++;
    }
    c++;
}
return cont;
}
int o(char *c){
int cont=0;
while(*c){
    switch(*c){
        case'o':
            cont++;
    }
    c++;
}
return cont;
}
int u(char *c){
int cont=0;
while(*c){
    switch(*c){
        case'u':
            cont++;
    }
    c++;
}
return cont;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema radica aquí:

```c
printf("la letra [a] aparece %i veces\n"), v_a(a);
```

El código de arriba es equivalente a esto:

```c
printf("la letra [a] aparece %i veces\n");
v_a(a);
```

En pocas palabras, primero se ejecuta la función `printf` y después `v_a`, sin embargo, en ningún momento le pasas a la función `printf`, el argumento para poder imprimir el número de veces que aparece `X` vocal en una oración.

**Solución:**

```c
printf("la letra [a] aparece %i veces\n", v_a(a));
```

**Recomendación:**

Crear una función por cada letra es sumamente redundante.

Así que propongo definir una función que tenga un parámetro adicional, en la cual reciba la vocal:

```c
int ObtenerVeces_vocal(char * c, char vocal)
{
    int cont=0;
    while(*c)
    {
        if(*c == vocal)
            cont++;
        c++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Su modo de uso sería:

```c
printf("la letra [a] aparece %i veces\n", ObtenerVeces_vocal(a, 'a');
printf("la letra [e] aparece %i veces\n", ObtenerVeces_vocal(a, 'e');
printf("la letra [i] aparece %i veces\n", ObtenerVeces_vocal(a, 'i');
printf("la letra [o] aparece %i veces\n", ObtenerVeces_vocal(a, 'o');
printf("la letra [u] aparece %i veces\n", ObtenerVeces_vocalu(a, 'u');
```